# How to prove this inequality sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

${b_{n}},b_{1}=1,b_{n}b_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)}$,where   $n \geq 3, n \in N_{+}$

Show that :

$ 1. b_{2n} < b_{2n+1} < b_{2n-1} $ ;

$ 2. b_{1} + b_{2} + b_{3} + \cdots + b_{n} > \sqrt{2n + 1} - 1 $.

Thank you !

Comment: What about $b_2,b_3$?

Comment: @Shuchang Zhang   ,$b_{2}$ and $b_{3} $can be calculated by $b_{n}b_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2(2n+1)}$.

Comment: I rewrite $n\geq3$ to $n\geq2$

Comment: @Shuchang Zhang ，please do not rewrite the proble! I copy it from my exercise book, after the range of n changed , it will affect the two proof.So I will rewrite back to the oringin.

Comment: Then $b_2$ must be given explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$b_nb_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\tag{1}$$
$$b_{n+1}b_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2n+3}\tag{2}$$
Dividing (1) by (2) obtains
$$b_n=\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}b_{n+2}>b_{n+2}$$
This proves the partial result $b_{2n+1}<b_{2n-1}$
Next apply mathematical induction on $n$.
It's easy to verify $b_2<b_1$ and assume for $n\leq k$ we have $b_{2k}<b_{2k+1}$, then
$$\frac{4k+3}{4k+1}b_{2k+2}<\frac{4k+5}{4k+3}b_{2k+3}$$
Or,
$$b_{2k+2}<\frac{16k^2+24k+5}{16k^2+24k+9}b_{2k+3}<b_{2k+3}$$
which shows the case $n=k+1$ holds. Then we can conclude $b_{2n}<b_{2n+1}<b_{2n-1}$.

For the second part, by employing AG inequality, 
$$b_n+b_{n+1}\geq2\sqrt{b_nb_{n+1}}=\sqrt\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$\begin{align}b_1+b_2+...+b_{n+1}=&(b_1+b_2+...+b_{n-1})+(b_n+b_{n+1})\\
>&(\sqrt{2n-1}-1)+\sqrt\frac1{2n-1}\\
=&\sqrt{2n+1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}-1\\
>&\sqrt{2n+1}-1\end{align}$$
Also the result concludes by induction. But the premise is that $n$ holds for only $n>k$ where case $n=k-1,k-2$ holds.

Comment: Sorry ，$b_nb_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)}$ ,my former evaluation is wrong,so I rewrite the question.Your solution is good ,the induction is a good try.

Comment: @user104677 You're welcome. So, why not give an upvote or accept it

Answer (score 0):

Since one has $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2(2n+1)b_n}$ and (replacing $n$ with
$n+1$) $b_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2(2n+3)b_{n+1}}$, we see that

$$
b_{n+2}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}b_n \tag{1}
$$

So if we put $u_n=b_{2n}$ and $v_n=b_{2n-1}$, we have

$$
u_{n+1}=\frac{4n+1}{4n+3}u_n, \ v_{n+1}=\frac{4n-1}{4n+1}v_n \tag{2}
$$

This shows that $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are both decreasing.
Let us show by induction that $P_n : u_n < v_{n+1}$ holds for all $n\geq 1$.

First, we have $u_1=b_2=\frac{1}{6}$ and $v_2=b_{3}=\frac{3}{5}$, so that $P_1$
is true.

Suppose that $P_n$ is true. Then

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+2}}=\frac{\frac{4n+1}{4n+3}u_n}{\frac{4n+3}{4n+5}v_{n+1}}=
\frac{(4n+1)(4n+5)}{(4n+3)^2}\frac{u_{n}}{v_{n+1}}=
\frac{16n^2+24n+5}{16n^2+24n+9}\frac{u_{n}}{v_{n+1}} \leq \frac{u_{n}}{v_{n+1}} \leq 1,
$$

so that $P_{n+1}$ is true also. This finishes the proof of $P_n$ by induction.

We thus have $u_n < v_{n+1} < v_n$ for all $n$, which answers question $1$.

Also, statement number 2 is false for $n=2$. We have $b_1+b_2=1+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{7}{6} \approx 1,167$ but $\sqrt{5}-3\approx 1,236$. So 
$b_1+b_2 < \sqrt{2\times 2+1}-1$.

Comment: Thank you, due to my false,I write a wrong relation between $b_n$ and $b_{n+1}$,now I write it to the right form:$b_nb_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)}$.

Comment: After I rewrite the question,would you please try again,prove statement number 2 is true for any integers n when n > 2, thank you.

Comment: ,I rewrite the question,Would you please show me your solution to statement No. 2?Thank you very much.